# Keyboard from EditText destroing Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have EditText, when i toutch this, keyboard will show, but instead of covering the bottom part of the application, it shifts all the elements at the top and makes them smaller, everything looks distorted ...
How do I display the keyboard so that it does not affect our layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this [Link:](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility.html)

You can add in your menifest for the activity you want to prevent such issue.
Also make sure if you are having a bit more content use scrollView as a parent.
And soft input mode as "adjustResize"

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

or

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

you can use as per your need.

> **adjustResize**
>
> to ensure that the system resizes your layout to the available space—which ensures that all of your layout content is accessible (even though it probably requires scrolling)—use this one.
>
> **adjustPan**
>
> The activity's main window is not resized to make room for the soft keyboard, and the contents of the window are automatically panned so that the current focus is never obscured by the keyboard and users can always see what they are typing.
>
> **adjustNothing**
>
> Do nothing with layouts