# Prevent specific view/layout for pushing up when keyboard is displayed

Tags: android

I have spent days trying to resolve this..
So I have a fragment layout. When I click a button, that fragment will show. Fragment has recycler(top) view and edittext(bottom) in it. So what i want is to show only the edittext layout will go up not including the recycler view layout,when I click the edittext and the keyboard is showing up.

Comment: Can you post your layout code here, that will help us for better solution

Comment: possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48968789/keyboard-from-edittext-destroing-layout/48970398#48970398

Answer (score 1):

In your Manifest Activity Try adding this line

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
```

This should not adjust anything

**Sample**

```
   <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"/>
```

Comment: that make all view does not adjust, not special view

Answer (score 0):

**To avoid pushing your layout/view up** *just go to your Manifest File* **and in the respective Activity add this** :-

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
```

eg.)

```
<activity
        android:name=".yourActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"/>
```

and **if you are facing this issue in any Fragment** , *then in your Manifest* file go to the parent Activity of this Fragment and add this line there.

Comment: that make all view does not adjust, not special view

Answer (score 0):

```
add configchanges tag in your activity tag in Manifest file.    

    <activity
                android:name=".ImageEditingActivity"
                android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|layoutDirection|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
                android:screenOrientation="landscape"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```

you can set SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_NOTHING in your activity tag or inside class, i am using it inside class in fragment while showing keyboard.

```
        private void showSoftKeyboard(InputMethodManager inputMethodManager, EditText addTxtEditText) {
            addTxtEditText.setFocusable(true);
            addTxtEditText.setEnabled(true);
            addTxtEditText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            addTxtEditText.setClickable(true);

            getActivity().getWindow()
            .setSoftInputMode(
             WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_NOTHING);

           inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInputFromWindow(addTxtEditText.getApplicationWindowToken(), 2, 0);
            addTxtEditText.requestFocus();
        }

    private void dismissSoftKeyboard(InputMethodManager inputMethodManager, EditText addTxtEditText) {
            addTxtEditText.setFocusable(false);
            addTxtEditText.setEnabled(false);
            addTxtEditText.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
            addTxtEditText.setClickable(false);
            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(addTxtEditText.getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);
            addTxtEditText.clearFocus();
        }
```